# setting mootools fx.morph height to auto instead of a fix height

Tags: mootools, mootools-fx

I'm trying to show my nav using fx.morph the code is as below:

```
 var fx = new Fx.Morph(_element, { 
     duration: 1000,transition:Fx.Transitions.Sine.easeOut
                                 });
 fx.start({
          'height': [0, 100]
           });
 }
```

it works well,the thing that i need is to set height from 0 to auto instead of 0 to 100.is there any solution to do that?I try auto and 100% but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle with your HTML so we can help you better?

Comment: i don't want the total code just need a solution to set height auto instead of  fixed height

Comment: Well I want to help you as good as I can and for that I would like to see a part of your HTML relevant to the question. Or just make a jsFiddle with a example of the problem with other code.

Comment: is it impossible?no one answered !!!!!

Comment: Mona I asked you for more details, if you provide them I am happy to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it myself.I just add a container and after that calculat the height of that container and us it as the height.

```
    var _element = el.getElement('.child_first_nav_mobile');
            if (_element) {

                var fx = new Fx.Morph(_element, { duration: 1000 });
                var autoheightdiv = _element;
                autoheightdiv.style.height='auto';
                var calcheight=autoheightdiv.offsetHeight
                fx.start({
                    'height': [0, calcheight] 
                    });
```